# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hello.ko: Operation not permitted

Tags: drivers, kernel

While writing a hello world kernel module, insmod command displays this error. I tried everything , but nothing worked.

```
~$ cd Desktop
~/Desktop$ cd hellomodule
~/Desktop/hellomodule$ make

make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/build M=/home/shivang_official/Desktop/hellomodule modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic'

~/Desktop/hellomodule$ su
Password: 
/Desktop/hellomodule# insmod ./hello.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hello.ko: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Yes, I used sudo. And please ask what information you need to answer the question ?

Comment: Yes. I did run make clean before make. But it was of no use.

Comment: So it looks like it may be a feature in more recent kernels related to unsigned code and secure boot [modprobe fails with "Operation not permitted"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543576/modprobe-fails-with-permission-denied)